# how to Upload xml data to db Table by check primary key in oracle

Tags: oracle, update, migration, xml

i want to upload xml file data to db table by checking the primary key and wants update the each row data.Here trid getting as a primary key.example


OFF
    1133
    2388977

is their any solution for upload xml to db table by check primary key in oracle ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using third party tool such as Toad for Oracle. There is a function to import the .xml file into database and of course it will check the primary key before loading the data.